# Fetch remote log, not the commits

Tags: git, logging, tortoisegit

How can I fetch the remote log without getting the changes/commits ?

I only want to view the log, if there is any new changes since my last `pull`. Basically avoiding having to `stash` or `commit` my changes first.

The git help files have this example, which in inverted form should give the result I want:

```
git log master --not --remotes=*/master
Shows all commits that are in local master but not in any remote repository master branches
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to fetch the changes, without merging them (i.e. don't use `pull`):

```
git fetch origin master
```

After that you can use `log` (and other tools) to have a look at the remote's branch:

```
git log FETCH_HEAD --not master
```

`FETCH_HEAD` is an alias to the latest fetched branch, in this case `origin/master`, just like `HEAD` is an alias to the latest commit of your currently checked out branch.