# git - list tag message on remote repositories

Tags: git

I retrieve the tags on remote repositories using `git ls-remote --tags https://github.com/myuser/myrepo`. The tags are annotated. The output provides the tags as below but doesn't provide the tag message. Is there any way I can retrieve the tag message as well? Perhaps something like on the [github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/tags/) I need to fetch the message on several repositories (e.g. 89) so I can't really clone each repository.

```
d5aef6e4d58cfe1549adef5b436f3ace984e8c86    refs/tags/gitgui-0.10.0
3d654be48f65545c4d3e35f5d3bbed5489820930    refs/tags/gitgui-0.10.0^{}
33682a5e98adfd8ba4ce0e21363c443bd273eb77    refs/tags/gitgui-0.10.1
729ffa50f75a025935623bfc58d0932c65f7de2f    refs/tags/gitgui-0.10.1^{}
ca9b793bda20c7d011c96895e9407fac2df9648b    refs/tags/gitgui-0.10.2
95dcfa3633004da0049d3d0fa03f80589cbcaf31    refs/tags/gitgui-0.10.2^{}
8c178f72b54f387b84388d093a920ae45b8659dd    refs/tags/gitgui-0.11.0
1c1fe1005c9dacc05a34eb892ae20ebb1904a33b    refs/tags/gitgui-0.11.0^{}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get commit logs/messages of a remote git repo without git clone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055398/is-it-possible-to-get-commit-logs-messages-of-a-remote-git-repo-without-git-clon)

Comment: I don't need to fetch the commit messages. Only the tag annotation/message. It doesn't seems a duplicate to me.

Comment: It's not a duplicate in the sense that the question is the same, but the answer the same. There is no way of retrieving tag messages from `git ls-remote` or any other standard Git command. The Git hosting platform that you use may provide a special API for the purpose, though.

Comment: @MagnusBäck thanks! It's quite a shame that the git remote commands are so limited.

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat any solution?

Comment: I got one! let's go back to Subversion...I missed it :(