# Remotely view GIT commit details without a local clone

Tags: git

What are the possible ways of getting commit details(comment,list of files, author etc) for a given commit ID hash without having to clone locally?

For example something like below? 
git show a303aa90779efdd2f6b9d90693e2cbbbe4613c1d -remote https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap.git

I am looking for the right syntax is this is possible. Appreciate your help..

Answer (score 0):

You can only view details and history of your local repository.
You have to clone the repository first.

This answer may give you some of the details you need:

[Is it possible to get commit logs/messages of a remote git repo without git clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055398/is-it-possible-to-get-commit-logs-messages-of-a-remote-git-repo-without-git-clon)