# bitbucket log command without local clone

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am new to `BITBUCKET`.

My requirement is to get the git log command executed without local clone 
Is it possible ?

```
git log <remote name/branch name> --after="2016-10-27T16:36:00-02:00" --before="2016-11-03T18:36:00-02:00"  --oneline  --pretty=format:%ce --name-status
```

If required i will mention the remote repository `URL` too in the above log command

Comment: This answer will help. [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055398/is-it-possible-to-get-commit-logs-messages-of-a-remote-git-repo-without-git-clon)

Comment: This too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941976/commit-history-on-remote-repository