# Find out the date/time for the last update of a branch in a remote Git repository via command line

Tags: git

I feel like I miss the forest for the trees... I just want to find out the date/time for the last update of a branch in a remote Git repository via command line.

For example, take `https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog.git`. If I view the branches for this repository on GitHub at https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/branches, right now there is a line following the `master` branch that says:

> Updated 2 months ago

That's the information I'm looking for. What's the `git` (or any) command one would use for that? Is this even possible without cloning the branch first?

Comment: Would you mind checking of any of the answers helps you and if so accept it? If not, help us to help you

Comment: I updated my answer for a new approach, but in general it is not possible to get the information you want without cloning (at least a part) of the repository. But I just read about `sparse-checkout` which might reduce the amount to download significantly. Will check and update my answer if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For github specifically:

```
curl -s https://github.com/<user>/<repository>/tree/<branch> | sed -n -E 's/.*<relative-time datetime="([^"]+)".*/\1/p'
```

Explanation:

- `curl` gets the html website containing the wished information

  - `-s` doesn't show any progress
- `sed`

  - `-n` ignore non-matching lines
  - `-E` extended regex
  - `'s/.*<relative-time datetime="([^"]+)".*/\1/p'`
  - `.*<relative-time datetime="([^"]+)".*` Searches for the line containing the `relative-time` tag
  - `\1` Replaces the match with the date of the last change
  - `p` In conjunction with `-n` will print only the match

Only downside:
The date will not be in a relative format (because that seems to be computed by javascript after the side loads)

---

#### Different approach that works with every git repository:

*Based on the answer to this question ["Is it possible to get commit logs/messages of a remote git repo without git clone"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27145694/1988796)*

```
$ git clone --branch <branch name> --single-branch <repo url> --depth=1
```

This will download just a single revision of a single branch of the repository.

From this point on you can simply use:

```
$ git log -1 --format=%cd
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
git log -1 --format=%cd
```

Comment: @emmi474 you need a local clone.  Accessing this data remotely isn't possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055398/is-it-possible-to-get-commit-logs-messages-of-a-remote-git-repo-without-git-clon

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
git log
```

And it'll show you all the previous updates. So you can checkout the commits by you or other people.