# Get Commit-Hash of specific file/folder from remote git-repo

Tags: git

Currently we do `git log --pretty=tformat:"%H" -n 1 folder/file` to retrieve the latest commit hash of the file in the current checked out branch. But this needs to have the git repo being cloned locally.

Is there a way to determine the commit hash of a specific file in a specific branch on the remote git repo?

I need a plain git command for this, not a command for a git interface like git or gitlab.

Comment: Just to make sure it's clear: by "the commit hash of the file", do you mean the most recent commit that changed that file, on a particular branch? And when you say "remote git repo", are you looking for a plain git command that operates without cloning, or something on a git interface like Github or Gitlab?

Comment: yes, the most recent commit of that file
and it has to be a git command.

Comment: @Uzlopak: "most recent commit of that file" is not necessarily the same as "most recent commit that **changed** the file". In fact unless the file was deleted even the latest commit of the branch will contain the file.

Comment: @JoachimSauer most recent commit that changed the file/folder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to get commit logs/messages of a remote git repo without git clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055398/is-it-possible-to-get-commit-logs-messages-of-a-remote-git-repo-without-git-clon)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to determine the commit hash of a specific file in a specific branch on the remote git repo?

Not exactly, no.  You can only do this with commits that exist locally, and there's no *guarantee* that any commit that *they* have, you also have.  So there are actually two problems here:

- First, you need to determine the hash ID that *they* use for *their* branch name.
- Then, having done the above, you need to make sure that *you* have *that commit* and its predecessors.

You can then use a local operation to find, locally, the local commit in which the file you care about was most recently changed, in the same way you're already doing it.  But you need to hit both of those two bullet points first.  The way to do *that* is to have the repository locally, add the other Git as a *remote*, and run `git fetch` to that remote, so that you get *remote-tracking names* that correspond to their branch names.

Let's say, for instance, that the URL for their Git repository is `$url`.  You can then use:

```
git remote add them $url
git fetch them
```

followed by a tiny modification to:

> `git log --pretty=tformat:"%H" -n 1 folder/file`

Just add `them/branchname` before the pathname (and, for general safety, add `--` before the pathname as well):

```
git log --pretty=tformat:"%H" -n 1 them/branchname -- folder/file
```

Note that you need only use `git remote add` *once*, but you need to run the `git fetch them` just before any scan, to pick up any new commits they have and get the updated value of their `branchname` into your `them/branchname`.

(You can optionally use `git fetch them branchname`, which will sometimes save a little bit of time.)